SSL Handshake Aborted Error with Coil in Kotlin
I'm currently working on a Kotlin project using coil3 for image loading. I'm encountering an SSL handshake aborted error with the following details:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
...
SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7b0998168998: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:592 0x7b09881aecf0:0x00000003)

I've tried adjusting the TLS versions and cipher suites that my client supports, and I've confirmed that the server is working as expected and supports the TLS versions I'm trying to use. I've also tried using a custom SSLSocketFactory that enables the necessary TLS versions on older devices. However, the issue persists.
Here's a snippet of my code:
val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .connectionSpecs(listOf(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS, ConnectionSpec.RESTRICTED_TLS))
    .build()

val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(LocalContext.current)
    .components {
        add(
            OkHttpNetworkFetcherFactory {
                client
            }
        )
    }
    .build()

val request = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
    .data("https://info.defcon.org/blobs/v_aerospace.png")
    .build()

AsyncImage(
    model = request,
    contentDescription = "logo",
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.White)
        .fillMaxSize(),
    imageLoader = imageLoader,
)

I'm using Android Studio Koala | 2023.3.2 Canary 2 as my IDE. The issue occurs on both older and newer Android versions.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I guess the issue is SSL problem and you need to Either ignore That certificate OR Trust All the Certificate. You can also provide the actual certificate for this.
Hope following code will work. Try these few lines of code before building the HttpClient connection.
//set self sign certificate
val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(object : X509TrustManager {
    override fun checkClientTrusted(
        chain: Array<out X509Certificate>?, 
        authType: String?
    ) {}

    override fun checkServerTrusted(
        chain: Array<out X509Certificate>?, 
        authType: String?
    ) {}

    override fun getAcceptedIssuers() = arrayOf<X509Certificate>()
})

val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, java.security.SecureRandom())
                
// Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
val sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory

// connect to server
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustAllCerts[0] as X509TrustManager)
    .hostnameVerifier{ _, _ -> true }
    .build()

